# Help using flags in my jsp

Tags: sql

This might be confusing, so just ask if a better explanation is needed.  I am trying to select certain teams for a particular user.  Here is my SELECT statement:

```
                          "SELECT "
                            + "team_id, "
                            + "add_date, "
                            + "campus, "
                            + "name, "
                            + "status "
                            + "request_type "
                        + "FROM SCHEMA_1.REQUEST "
                        + "WHERE add_user = ?");
```

I have three request_types (New, Edit, and Delete) and two status'(Approved and Requested).  There can be multiple requests for a team_id, and a status for each one of those requests. I am using one HTML table, and want to show two things:

-The most recent(according to 'add_date') 'Edit' request for a 'team_id' that has the status of 'Approved'.

-Any 'New' request for a 'team_id' with a status of 'Requested'.

I figure there is some kind of flag I can write in java for this, just looking for some sample code, or any help with this.  Again if this is too confusing just let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not necessarily a Java/JSP problem. You need to get Java/JSP out of your head when struggling with SQL. It are two entirely distinct languages. Best would be to use some DB admin tool to create/test SQL queries and then once you get it to work, copy the query in Java code. Java is here just the executor/messenger who has totally no knowledge of how SQL works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The most recent(according to 'add_date') 'Edit' request for a 'team_id' that has the status of 'Approved' :

  `SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_1.REQUEST WHERE team_id=<specified_id> AND status='Approved' ORDER BY add_date DESC LIMIT 1`
- Any 'New' request for a 'team_id' with a status of 'Requested' :

  `SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_1.REQUEST WHERE team_id=<specified_id> AND status='Requested`'

I would recommend you use `ENUM` for your `status`.

Comment: I am not familiar with the SELECT FIRST 1 command. The only reason I ask is because I do not want to SELECT *, I only want to select certain fields.

Comment: I changed SELECT FIRST 1 to LIMIT 1 (not even sure the former exists). You can replace `*` with the list of fields you want, as in your example.